# How to call Output Menu Item and execute Report in Batch Mode?

Tags: reporting-services, batch-processing, ssrs-2012, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have an issue in **BATCH** mode.
If I call this line command:

```
Args         parameters = new Args();
MenuFunction menuFunction;

parameters.record(myCurrentTableRecord);
parameters.caller(this);
menuFunction = new MenuFunction(menuitemoutputstr(Report_Name), MenuItemType::Output);
menuFunction.run(parameters);
```

in *Client* mode, it work well. Generate the report.

If I execute this command in **BATCH** mode I get an error like this:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Dynamics.Ax.Application.dll26.netmodule but was not handled in user code
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Dynamics.Ax.Application.Report_NameContract' to type 'Dynamics.Ax.Application.TradeDocumentReportContract'.
>
> at
>   Dynamics.Ax.Application.TradeDocumentReportController.Prerunmodifycontract() in TradeDocumentReportController.preRunModifyContract.xpp:line 8
>   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.SrsPrintMgmtController.Outputreports() in SrsPrintMgmtController.outputReports.xpp:line 65
>   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.ReportName.Runprintmgmt() in Report_Name.runPrintMgmt.xpp:line 28
>   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.SrsPrintMgmtController.Run() in SrsPrintMgmtController.run.xpp:line 30
>   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.SysOperationController.Startoperation() in SysOperationController.startOperation.xpp:line 10
>   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.SrsReportRunController.Startoperation() in SrsReportRunController.startOperation.xpp:line 19
>   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.SrsPrintMgmtController.Startoperation() in SrsPrintMgmtController.startOperation.xpp:line 14
>   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.SrsPrintMgmtFormLetterController.Startoperation() in SrsPrintMgmtFormLetterController.startOperation.xpp:line 14
>   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.Report_Name.main(Args _args) in Report_Name.main.xpp:line 14

The Class used to define my Report `extends` the `TradeDocumentReportController` class.

I executed a *Full CIL* , *restarted* my AOS/Report Services etc...

There is any way to execute the report in BACTH Mode? Have I to pass any parameters?

Thanks in advice.
Enjoy.

Comment: We can't see the cast attempt, we can't see the class definitions ant it' unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, `Report_NameContract` doesn't extend `TradeDocumentReportContract`.

It might be a good idea for you to debug the batch job using Visual Studio by attaching to process `Ax32Serv.exe`, if you want to see what exactly is going on and where the process doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @10p. I done the Visual Studio debug, the error is this:
`An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Dynamics.Ax.Application.dll26.netmodule but was not handled in user code`

In Batch not add extends thw class. Have you any idea? I appreaciated you help.Thanks.

`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Dynamics.Ax.Application.Report_NameContract' to type 'Dynamics.Ax.Application.TradeDocumentReportContract'.`